# XPath how to get all text in paragraph tag and all its inner nested texts such as bold words

Tags: html, xpath, text, paragraph

I have the below html:

```
<p>Text a
    <b>Bold inner</b>
Text b.</p>
```

I want an xpath to get all the text i.e. I want returned: `Text a Bold inner Text b.`.

This: `/p/text()` will only get me `Text a`. How can I do this?